# Word Macro not applying outline after clearing formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word

This macro is straight from the macro recorder but sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.  I figured out that if I clear formatting with ctrl-spacebar then the macro doesn't work.  And it also seems to change the kerning slightly.  But if I go into the Font menu and click on "no outline", then the macro will work.

```
  With Selection.Font
    .Outline = True
  End With
```

Comment: It works for me, following the steps you mention. The outline settings aren't the same as the original, but it does change. If you zoom the display can you see a difference?

Comment: yeah even zoomed in or with large font it seems to work intermittently.  I think it may have something to do with Styles vs editing the text directly but I can't figure out a pattern.